# Not able to debug break point in Angular 11, TypeScript & VS Code

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying an angular app for the first time, I'm able to launch it with ng serve. However, I'm not able to trigger break points within VS Code. I also don't seem to have a launch.json. What steps do I take to be able to debug my app?

[image: Trying to trigger break point in Typescript]

Comment: If you didn't create your app with the Angular CLI, then you probably won't have the launch configuration (launch.json/tasks.json). You'll need to create them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right approach to do it, but the way I've managed to stop at breakpoints in my angular application (in dev) is by opening the developer tools in your browser, look for the 'sources' tab, click it and then in the left panel look for a 'webpack'. It should look something like this (its at the very end of the picture).

[image: Source tab view]

Once you collapsed the webpack section, you basically will see your Angular project folder, look for the files you want to add a breakpoint to and add it from there. It always works for me.

[image: Webpack section collapsed]

Comment: That works pretty well. So far, I have not found limitations and seem to be able to do what I need to do.